# Linux bash sleep if the command execution is fast

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sleep

On linux bash I want to ensure my command execution takes 10 seconds or longer so if it finishes early I need to add some sleep so the overall execution would take more than 10 seconds.

If you are wondering why it is to ensure a third party background daemon job (running every 10 seconds) will pick it up.

What I have is:
`sleep 10; my_command.sh`
but this will add 10 seconds to overall execution so if the command itself takes 10 seconds or more it will still add another 10 seconds. Is there a way to only sleep if the command is taking less than 10 seconds?

EDIT:
I also want the exit code of `my_command.sh` to be returned upon end of execution. So the whole command including sleep should return the same exit code as `my_command.sh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `sleep 10` at the background and `wait` for it to complete after `my_command.sh` finishes.

```
sleep 10 & my_command.sh; wait
```

If there are other background jobs this will wait for them too, though. In that case you can either run it in a **subshell**, e.g:

```
( sleep 10 & my_command.sh; wait )
```

or keep `sleep 10`'s PID in a variable and wait for it, thus `my_command.sh` will be run in **current execution environment**, e.g:

```
sleep 10 & pid=$!; my_command.sh; wait "$pid"
```

Comment: Yes I just want the sleep for the commands that take less than 10 seconds, so if it takes more than 10 seconds no sleep is needed and it should return as it would normally do if you just run that command.

Comment: @oguzismail  there a way to make sure the whole command return the same exit code as `my_command.sh`?

Comment: @danial if you're going to use the subshell one `(sleep 10 & my_command.sh; e=$?; wait; exit $e)` would work. Keeping its exit value is the only option I guess.

Answer (score 4):

With bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
SECONDS=0
# place your code here
rest=$((10-$SECONDS))
[[ $rest -gt 0 ]] && sleep $rest
```

**Update:** Use a function and save returncode to a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
  local SECONDS=0
  local returncode

  # place your code here
  returncode=$?

  rest=$((10-$SECONDS))
  [[ $rest -gt 0 ]] && sleep $rest

  return $returncode
}

foo
echo $?
```

Comment: @Cyrus How do I make sure the whole command returns the same exit code as my command?